# How to setup distance between two objects

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

A week ago i started learning python turtle, an i would like to ask somebody what should i do with setting distance between these objects. Three objects - i use goto method with random but these objects is setting very close to each other. I know something about the method distance, but im not always successful with it.
Thanx for every help

```
import turtle
import time
import random
my_space = turtle.Screen()
my_space.setup(width=1200, height=700)
my_space.title("Dula´s Ford Game")
my_space.addshape("ford.gif")
my_space.tracer(0)

ford = turtle.Turtle()
ford.speed(0)
ford.penup()
ford.goto(-400,0)
ford.shape("ford.gif")
ford.direction = "stop"

car1 = turtle.Turtle("circle")
car2 = turtle.Turtle("turtle")
car3 = turtle.Turtle()
car_list = [car1,car2,car3] 

for car in car_list:
    car.penup()
    car.speed(0)
    other_car_x = 400 
    other_car_y = random.randint(-100,100)
    car.goto(other_car_x,other_car_y) 
    car.seth(180)
    car.fd(10)
    
def right():
    rside = ford.xcor()
    ford.setx(rside+20) 
    if rside > 500:
        ford.setx(rside)
    else:
        ford.setx(rside+20)
def left():
    lside = ford.xcor()
    if lside < -500:
        ford.setx(lside)
    else:
        ford.setx(lside-20)
def up():
    upside = ford.ycor()
    if upside > 100:
        ford.sety(upside)
    else:
        ford.sety(upside+20)
     
def down():
    downside = ford.ycor()
    if downside < -100:
        ford.sety(downside)
    else:
        ford.sety(downside-20)
def start():
    ford.direction = "start"

my_space.listen()
my_space.onkeypress(start,key="space")
my_space.onkeypress(right,key="Right")
my_space.onkeypress(left,key="Left")
my_space.onkeypress(up,key="Up")
my_space.onkeypress(down,key="Down")


while True:
    my_space.update()
    if ford.direction == "start":   
        for car in range(0,random.randint(1,len(car_list))):
            speedy = random.randint(15,50)
            enemy = car_list[car]
            enemy.speed(speedy)
            enemy.fd(speedy)
            if enemy.xcor()<-500:
                enemy.hideturtle()
                enemy.goto(400,random.randint(-100,100))
                if enemy.distance(enemy) < 30:
                    enemy.goto(400,random.randint(-100,100))
                    enemy.showturtle()
    
    
        
      
    time.sleep(0.1)
     
 



my_space.exitonclick()
```

Comment: What do you mean by setting distance between objects, exactly? Note that `while True: sleep()` isn't a great idiom for a rendering event loop. Prefer `ontimer`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I try to solve problem with distance between three objects in car_list . With the method goto which i used in cycle i selected these objects to random ycor,xcor stay const. Ycor is setup randomly in range. Due to random funct.  they have been selected into three different pos - the problem lies that sometimes one object is stuck on or lies very close to another one. I need some condition regarding the distance between these three object to prevent that objects distance between each other will be (lets we say) under 20px-if it will be-random will be repeating in that case

Comment: If you want to find the distance between turtles, can't you use Pythagoras' Theorem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `distance()` is what you want.  You're trying to keep objects in their own (Y coordinate) lane, independent of their distance from each other on the (X coordinate) road.  What we need is an `any()` test to verify that our y position is sufficiently far away from everyone else's y position:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint, choice

def right():
    x = turtle.xcor()

    if x <= 500:
        turtle.setx(x + 20)

def left():
    x = turtle.xcor()

    if x >= -500:
        turtle.setx(x - 20)

def up():
    y = turtle.ycor()

    if y <= 100:
        turtle.sety(y + 20)

def down():
    y = turtle.ycor()

    if y >= -100:
        turtle.sety(y - 20)

def start():
    turtle.state = 'running'
    move()

def move():
    if turtle.state == 'running':
        this_car = choice(enemies)
        distance = randint(15, 50)
        this_car.forward(distance)

        if this_car.xcor() < -500:
            this_car.hideturtle()

            this_car_x = 400
            this_car_y = randint(-100, 100)

            while any(other_car != this_car and abs(this_car_y - other_car.ycor()) < 50 for other_car in enemies):
                this_car_y = randint(-100, 100)

            this_car.goto(this_car_x, this_car_y)

        this_car.showturtle()

        screen.update()
        screen.ontimer(move, 100)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=1200, height=600)
screen.title("Dula´s Ford Game")
screen.tracer(0)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('turtle')
turtle.penup()
turtle.setx(-400)
turtle.state = 'stopped'  # user property

enemies = []

for shape in ['circle', 'square', 'classic']:
    enemy = Turtle(shape)
    enemy.penup()

    this_car_x = 400
    this_car_y = randint(-100, 100)

    while any(abs(other_car.ycor() - this_car_y) < 50 for other_car in enemies):
        this_car_y = randint(-100, 100)

    enemy.goto(this_car_x, this_car_y)

    enemy.setheading(180)
    enemy.forward(10)

    enemies.append(enemy)

screen.onkeypress(start, key='space')
screen.onkeypress(right, key='Right')
screen.onkeypress(left, key='Left')
screen.onkeypress(up, key='Up')
screen.onkeypress(down, key='Down')
screen.listen()

screen.update()
screen.mainloop()
```